# nw.js, how to detect code changes and refresh the page

Tags: node.js, nw.js

`nw.js` has [SDK](https://nwjs.io/downloads/) version, the version can be reload window and open devtool (console.log) through right mouse button + R and F12.

the reload is poor performance and inconvenient, it will close the window and reopen the window, is there any way to detect code changes automatically update page?

like `node.js` `supervisor`, or other development environment?